# MySQL - Rename Column

Tags: php, mysql

How to rename mysql column from `help` to `content` in my table `tbl_help`

```
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE tbl_help " . "CHANGE COLUMN help content;");
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You've got to include the definition of the column in the change column statement (not sure why, but that's what the documentation says.)

So this should work:

```
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE tbl_help " . "CHANGE COLUMN help content VARCHAR(200) ;");
```

Answer (score 7):

From [mySql Doc pages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html):

You can rename a column using a `CHANGE old_col_name new_col_name column_definition` clause.

Comment: thanks for the page. sorry, what is the column_definition? it's syntax like TEXT INT etc?

Comment: Yes, it's the type, constraints, etc. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html for the exact definition.

Comment: It's the column type, length, charset etc.

Comment: @Mike B - Yeah.. getting blur. Actually I could not understand without fully examples.

Comment: This is all well and good, but does it screw up foreign keys, indexes and constraints?