# Rename column name with php and MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, alter-table, alter

I am trying to change the name of the column c to novaC with php and mysql. Everywhere I look seems to give the same solution but it doesn't seem to work:

```
if(isset($_GET["rename"])){
    mysql_query("ALTER TABLE myTable
    RENAME COLUMN c to novaC");
}
```

If I type: `ALTER TABLE aaa RENAME COLUMN c to novaC` directly in MySql it gives:

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COLUMN c to novaC' at line 2
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Any errors?

Comment: No errors, nothing change

Comment: Then show us the sql schema. And btw [**please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: If I type: ALTER TABLE aaa
RENAME COLUMN c to novaC directly in MySql it gives: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COLUMN c to novaC' at line 2

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655599/mysql-rename-column

Comment: @jOk: I am learning php. If mysql is not recommended, why is w3Schools teaching it? this is where I learned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
alter table tablename change oldColumn newColumn varchar(10) ;
```

[Reference : Alter Table - MySQL Command](http://php.about.com/od/learnmysql/p/alter_table.htm)

Answer (score 5):

```
if(isset($_GET["rename"])){ 
    mysql_query("ALTER TABLE myTable CHANGE c  novaC varchar(9999)"); 
}
```

[The MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: The `CHANGE` requires you to specify the "column_definition" as well.  So that query would cause an error.

Comment: @AaronW. oh sorry i forgot it!